# optimize the following query time in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, workbench

```
select *
from ((select 'Temp', r.*
       from tab1 r 
       where (r.fa, r.date, r.status) not in (select r1.fa, r1.date, r1.status from tab2 r1)
      ) union all
      (select 'report', r.* 
       from tab2 r 
       where (r.fa, r.date, r.status) not in (select r1.fa, r1.date, r1.status from tab1 r1)
      )
     ) temp
order by fa;
```

As the data is increasing the query time is increasing. Please provide solution to optimize the time even if data keeps on increasing

Comment: What database system are you on? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc

Comment: my sql work bench

Comment: Relevant information for query optimization questions include the current query/optimizer plan, existing indexes, and approximate table sizes.

Comment: wat does dat mean, cn i write d same query in such a way dat the execution time decreases, sometimes it even takes more thn a minute

Comment: Your query looks fine. But you also need to have the right indexes. What Klas meant is: write `explain ` directly infront of your query (`explain select * from ...`) and add the output to your question. This is the query plan. Also do `show create table tab1;` (and the same for `tab2`) and add the result to your question. This will tell us about your tables, and especially the indexes.

Comment: @p.g - Please use whole words; some of us old-timers don't know thumb-speak.

Answer (score 0):

so you want data A + B -(a intersect B). For that you are using 1 union and 2 not in clause. I tried to eliminate those in following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT X.*, COUNT(DISTINCT CN) OVER(PARTITION BY r.fa,r.date,r.status) CNT
FROM (
SELECT  'Temp' CN,r.* 
FROM    tab1 r 
UNION ALL
SELECT  'report' CN,r.* 
FROM    tab2 r 
)X)Y
WHERE Y.CNT=1
```

Basically first you should select all records using UNION ALL instead UNION. after that filter out those records which appeared in both tables(tab1, tab2) for that you can use analytical function.

Comment: Limitation:  `OVER(PARTITION BY...)` is available only in MariaDB 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, you should start with indexes:

- `tab1(r.fa, r.date, r.status)`
- `tab2(r.fa, r.date, r.status)`

This should speed the `not in` portion of the queries.  There isn't a way around the `order by`.

In general, using a subquery unnecessary imposes additional costs.  However, because you are using `order by`, the subquery probably doesn't make a difference in terms of performance.

Comment: cn u plz write the exact query

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE (a,b) ...` has never been well optimized in MySQL.  Avoid the construct.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` has only recently been improved, but still it is not as good as `EXISTS( SELECT * ...)` or `LEFT JOIN .. ON ..`.  Reformulate.

`NOT IN`, plus both of the above can be reformulated into `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... IS NULL`

You don't need the outer `SELECT`, you can sort a `UNION` thus:

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... )
ORDER BY ...    -- applies to UNION
```

Optionally the `SELECTs` could also have `ORDER BY`, but it is useful only(?) if you have a `LIMIT`.